# How to generate a Consul template inside a Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm, hashicorp-vault, consul-template

I have a Helm Chart for a Spring Boot application that gets its database credentials injected by the Hashicorp Vault agent injector.

This is a snippet from the generated deployment manifest in the dev environment.

```
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: "app"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-database.properties: "secret/data/app/dev/database"
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-database.properties: |
          {{ with secret "secret/data/app/dev/database" }}
          spring.datasource.username: {{ .Data.data.username }}
          spring.datasource.password: {{ .Data.data.password }}
          {{ end }}
```

To be able to specify the path to the secret and the name of the generated secrets file in the `values.yaml`, I've constructed this template:

```
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: "{{ .Values.vault.role }}"
        {{ print "vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-" .Values.vault.secretFileName }}: "{{ .Values.vault.secretPath }}"
        {{ print "vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-" .Values.vault.secretFileName }}: |
          {{`
          {{ with secret "`}} {{- .Values.vault.secretPath -}}  {{`" }}
          spring.datasource.username: {{ .Data.data.username }}
          spring.datasource.password: {{ .Data.data.password }}
          {{ end }}
          `}}
```

It works as intended, but I don't think it's very elegant.

I've also tried this approach:

```
      annotations:
        vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: "true"
        vault.hashicorp.com/role: "{{ .Values.vault.role }}"
        {{ print "vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-" .Values.vault.secretFileName }}: "{{ .Values.vault.secretPath }}"
        {{ print "vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-" .Values.vault.secretFileName }}: |
          {{ print "{{ with secret " .Values.vault.secretPath " }}" }}
          {{ print "spring.datasource.username: {{ .Data.data.username }}" }}
          {{ print "spring.datasource.password: {{ .Data.data.password }}" }}
          {{ print "{{ end }}" }}
```

Which I feel is slightly better, but I'm still not happy with it.

So my question is: **Is there a better way to do it?**

Answer (score 1):

I am using this way in my helm Chart

```
  annotations:
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject: true
    vault.hashicorp.com/role: {{ $.Values.injector.role }}
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-secret-app: kv/k8s-{{ $.Values.environment }}/{{ $.Values.APP_NAME }}
    vault.hashicorp.com/agent-inject-template-app: |
      {{`{{ with secret "`}} kv/k8s-{{- $.Values.environment -}}/{{ $.Values.APP_NAME }}  {{`" }}
      {{ range $key, $value := .Data }}
      export {{ $key }}={{ $value }}
      {{ end }}`}}
```